# How do I fix the CSS Link Hover?

Tags: html, css

```
.navlinks {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Mark Pro;
  font-style: normal;
  display: block;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

.navlinks:hover{
  transform: translateY(1) !important;
}
```

I have been trying to get the hover working, but doesn't seem to work, Can anyone help me solve this issue,
Honestly I am not able to understand what is wrong in the code
Bdw the above CSS is applied to a `<a>` link

Comment: `translateY(..)` expects a distance. `1` is not a distance.

Comment: To add to @NiettheDarkAbsol comment: You want to translate it 1 _what_?  1px? 1vw? 1vh? 1em? 1 .... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into how [translateY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY) works

The value needed is a

> **length** or **percentage** representing the ordinate of
> the translating vector. A percentage value refers to the height of the
> reference box defined by the transform-box property.

So it's up to you to use it as you want.

If you want to move it with

**px**:

```
.navlinks:hover{
  transform: translateY(50px) !important;
}
```

**Percentage**:

```
.navlinks:hover{
  transform: translateY(25%) !important;
}
```

See [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) for all available length (px, vh, vw, etc...).

Comment: Hey Man. Thanks for the clarification, really appreciate it

Comment: Feel free to validate this answer if it is what you expected as an answer